# How to avoid new line coming between two tables when they are inserted dynamically

Tags: jquery

Here is my jQuery code to append two tables to a DIV.

```
 var str = "<table><tr><td>Hello</td></tr></table>";
 $('body').append(str+str);
```

But By the default these two tables are coming in two rows.
For example current output is

```
 Hello
 Hello
```

But I want like this

```
 Hello Hello
```

Thanks

Comment: +1 for making me scratch my head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "<table style='display:inline-block; *display: inline; _height: 30px;'><tr>   <td>Hello</td></tr></table>";

$('body').append(str+' '+str);
```

Tested in IE7,8,9, Chrome, Firefox. IE hacks borrowed from [here](http://flipc.blogspot.com/2009/02/damn-ie7-and-inline-block.html)

Answer (score 1):

`<table>` elements are block elements by default, so (like, e.g., `<div>` and `<p>`, amongst many) they will start on a new line by default. You can change this with CSS by setting `display: table-cell` or `display: inline-block`:

```
<table style="display: inline-block">
```

Or, better, in the stylesheet:

```
table {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Note that this behaviour has nothing to do with whether the elements were added with jQuery, but you can also set the style with jQuery:

```
$("table").css({display: "inline-block"});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hbCyK/1/

Comment: which browser does this work in? Doesn't in Chrome. And btw, isn't inline the default value?

Comment: I see you have changed to be like mine now. Good

Comment: changed again. But inline-block has incomplete implementation in IE6 and IE7. See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: @PenchoIlchev - I thought tables were block by default? You're right that "inline" doesn't work for table elements in Chrome - as soon as I went to add the demo in jsfiddle I realised and changed it to "table-cell", but I think that doesn't work in IE. So I've gone with "inline-block" (though I left a mention of "table-cell"), which should work in everything except perhaps IE 7 and older (pretty sure it works in 8 ^ 9).

Comment: @nnnnnn I have used "inline" and it is working fine in Mozilla. Does this work in every browser?

Comment: Sorry to have changed my answer a couple of times in only a few minutes. I'm not sure if there is a single "display" setting that will work in all browsers, if by "all" you want to include old IE. "inline" doesn't seem to work in Chrome. I'm pretty sure "table-cell" doesn't work in older IE, though I don't have that handy to test. Have a look at the quirksmode.org link that Pencho provided.

Comment: @PenchoIlchev - Yes, I mentioned that in a previous comment. Is there a single setting that works in all browsers though?